# Checking if all values are null inside an initialised object

Tags: c#, list, null

I have some code that reads data from Excel sheets & put to List.

Now here comes a scenario that user copy some valid data then leaves a lot of rows empty & again then copy valid data. This reads a lot of empty rows. I am using some old code for excel read & that might be used somewhere else so I don't wish to mess up with that.

The problem is I have a lot of object inside List that are initialised but all values are null. So I ended up checking all attribuets in if like:

```
if (lstConsolidatedData != null)
{
    foreach (var lst in lstConsolidatedData)
    {
         if(lst.a!=null && lst.b!=null && lst.c!=null //& so on....)
         {
           //some stuff...
         }
    }
}
```

I know this is not wither best or maintainable way since excel sheets can be modified & thus whole columns list code need to be changed again & again for a single column added or removed from excel.

**Is there any way to check all values inside `lst` for null in a single statement?**
some thing like `lst.all !=null`

Any idea if not code will also work for me.

Please note `lst==null` is `false`

EDIT: using answers from below I am getting this error

[image]

EDIT: 
`o.GetType().GetProperties().Any(c => c.GetValue(o) == null)` works for **any** null but What I actually want to delete rows which contains no data in **all columns** not for particular one or two column. Issue is not resolved by `o.Item1 != null && ...` also since name/number of columns changes frequently.

Comment: What is the type of 'lstConsolidatedData'

Comment: What is `a`, `b` and others?  Are they properties of class or fields?

Comment: @Alireza, lstConsolidatedData is List<ConsolidatedData> where ConsolidatedData is a custom datatype or a class.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev a, b are properties of class.

Comment: @PranavSingh: what kind of properties? The core question is: why do you store columns as fields in your class at all? Use a collection type instead (f.e. `List<string> Columns`). Then it's easy: `bool allColumnsNotNull = lst.Columns.All(c => c != null)` and you don't have to care about new or removed columns.

Comment: If you are using `this`, you should put it in a method, like I said. Also, did you include `using System.Reflection`?

Comment: I wish to remove the column name dependency from code as it can change time to time, so I ended up something different. I am answering the question as this might help someone else. I know this is different from what I asked but resolved actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up digging down into old code & before turning dataset into List I deleted empty rows using code:

```
        //Deleting empty records from Datset
        foreach (DataTable source in result.Tables)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow currentRow = source.Rows[i];
                bool isEmpty = false;
                foreach (var colValue in currentRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(colValue.ToString()))
                    {
                        isEmpty = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        isEmpty = true;

                }
                if (isEmpty)
                    source.Rows[i].Delete();
            }
        }
        result.AcceptChanges();
```

Don't forget `.AcceptChanges()` since it actually save the changes done to dataset without which no records are removed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use reflection to do this, but beware that it carries performance losses over doing it explicitly.

```
public bool IsAnyPropertyNull(object o)
{
    return o.GetType().GetProperties().Any(c => c.GetValue(o) == null);
}
```

There is, however, no built-in expression to reduce the `o.Item1 != null && o.Item2 != null && ...` type syntax.

Also, I'm assuming the values you're talking about are properties. You could also use `GetFields` or whatever you need if that's more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, yes we are talking about properties here. Let me check if it works for me.

Comment: @PranavSingh what version of C# are you using? I can't repro your error, curiously. You *could* try the overload `c.GetValue(o, null)`, but I'm not sure whether that works either.

Comment: `.Any(c => c.GetValue(o, null)== null` works for any null but What I actually want to delete rows which contains no data in all columns not for particular one or two column. Issue is not resolved by `o.Item1 != null && ...` also since name/number of columns changes frequently. Thanks for help

Comment: Then change it to `All` instead of `Any`, then you can call `lstConsolidatedData = lstConsolidatedData.Where(c => !AreAllPropertiesNull(c)).ToList()`, and that should give you what you want, at least within the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

As Mathew Huagen pointed out using reflection to get properties and then checking their values seems to be fine. However, this has a big caveat that is there may be some properties you don't want to be checked. To solve this,you can either put them inside a list (as Tim Schmelter mentioned), or you can decorate desired properties of `ConsolidatedData` with a custom attribute to distinguish them:

```
public class ConsolidatedData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public object PropertyOne { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public object PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public class NotNull : Attribute {    }
```

Then checking against null is safe when you filter out the properties not having `NotNull` attribute:

```
ConsolidatedData v = new ConsolidatedData();
bool allNotNull = v.GetType().GetProperties()
                   .Where(p => null != (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(NotNull)) as NotNull))
                   .All(p=>p.GetValue(v) !=null );
```

Here property `Id` is not get checked.

Comment: This could be useful but the constraint is properties can be nullable so marking them `NotNull` doesn't make much sense. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method for your `ConsolidatedData` like this;

```
public static bool IsAnyPropNull(this ConsolidatedData cdata)
{
    return cdata.GetType().GetProperties().Any(p => p.GetValue(this) == null);
}
```

And you could then filter your list with a one-liner;

```
var filteredList = lstConsolidatedData.Where(cd => !cd.IsAnyPropNull()).ToList();
```

This will return a list of all object without nulls. If you want the nulls, remove the `!`, ofcourse.

Edit;

Wow, my answer is almost the same as Matthew Haugen's... both should work fine, even though the implementation is slightly different.